# How to preview multiple views in the same canvas SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

[image]

```swift
struct CardDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CardDetailView(viewModel: .init(labelLabelViewModel: LabelLabel.ViewModel(topText: "hello", bottomText: .lorem)))
            .previewDevice("iPhone 14 Pro Max")
        CardDetailView(viewModel: .init(labelLabelViewModel: LabelLabel.ViewModel(topText: "hello", bottomText: .lorem)))
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
            .previewDevice("iPhone 14 Pro Max")
        CardDetailView(viewModel: .init(labelLabelViewModel: LabelLabel.ViewModel(topText: "hello", bottomText: .lorem)))
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
            .previewDevice("iPhone SE (3rd generation)")
        CardDetailView(viewModel: .init(labelLabelViewModel: LabelLabel.ViewModel(topText: "hello", bottomText: .lorem)))
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
            .previewDevice("iPhone SE (3rd generation)")
        
    }
}
```

I specified multiple versions to display.  All returned to the same preview property.  However, the canvas is only showing one preview view at a time.  I want to see all four at the same time.  Like I see on other dev's views.

[image]

Answer (score 29):

The ability to show multiple independent previews in a single canvas was **removed** in Xcode 14. Apple engineers answered this explicitly in the official WWDC 2022 Slack. [One response:](https://www.swiftui-lab.com/digital-lounges-2022#previews-1)

> We’ve been getting some questions regarding the new previews experience where each preview is given its own tab, and folks are wondering if there is a way to instead have multiple previews in the same tab.
>
> Each view in the `PreviewProvider` now shows in its own tab. If the individual views are differently configured rows for a list or can be combined in a `VStack` then a single preview could be used for seeing the different configurations. We’d love feedback if you have a unique case that you don’t think is covered by the current solutions!

[Another response:](https://www.swiftui-lab.com/digital-lounges-2022#previews-6)

> Each view in the `PreviewProvider` now shows in its own tab, and there are two ways to see multiple configurations in one tab.
>
> First, you can see multiple previews in the same tab for variations in device settings by using the new variants mode, accessible from the bottom bar of the canvas.
>
> Second, for multiple previews of the same view but with different inputs, you can make a single preview of a `List` or `VStack` that contains those different configurations. This is particularly helpful with rows of a `List` as the `List` will also show those views with the correct list styling and metrics.

You can use the Variants menu (at the bottom of the canvas) to show multiple variations of a single preview:

[image: the canvas variants menu]

But beyond that, each view in a `PreviewProvider` gets its own canvas tab.

Comment: This is a backwards step.

I want to see two previews of my view side by side.

Comment: Yea what the hell Apple? This is nonsense and is the opposite of being helpful. Why don't you leave it to the dev to decide at least?

Comment: VStack doesn't support `previewDevice`, which means there's no way to compare a view on a 40mm and 49mm watch side by side.

Answer (score 10):

You can still add multiple previews . By using new SwiftUI MACRO

You will see the preview tabs in the canvas section

```
    #Preview("On") {
        Button("hello on")
    }
    
    #Preview("Off") {
        Button("hello off")
    }
```

Comment: This is the way to go, from Xcode 15 onward!